# Replace text with dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I have this fiddle, when i replace a text with dots:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/1750/

```
var p=$('#fos');
var divh=$('#fos').height();
while (p[0].scrollHeight>divh) {
    p.text(function (index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
    });
}
```

Its working, but:

When i copy exactly this code in my website, i get this error in console:

```
TypeError: p[0] is undefined        

while (p[0].scrollHeight>divh) {
```

Coudl anybody explain to me why fiddle is working, but on server it isnt?

Greetings!

Comment: Do you have an _Element_ with _id_ `fos` on your page?

Comment: Wrap your code in a document ready or put your code at the bottom of the page.

Comment: i have no element with "id fos" , code is in "document ready" and at bottom of page already

Comment: try `console.log(p.length)` and see what you get in the console. It should be `1` for your code to work.

Comment: `var p=$('#fos');` means use _jQuery_ to find all elements with `id=fos` and call this `p` (an _id_ should be unique), so without such an element, there is no `p[0]` and hence you get your error

Comment: seems like ` '#fos'` is not being found in dom

Answer (score 1):

`i have no element with "id fos"`...

There's is your answer. `var p` is undefined because it has nothing to select. Which is why it doesn't have an element at the index zero.

Find the location of the text you want to transform and assign `p` to it (or change its id):

```
var p = $('#myTextId');
```